# How to write user-defined functions to determine whether card is Amex, Mastercard or Visa for Luhn algorithm program

Tags: java

I'm writing a Java program that Validates Credit Card. The program can prompt user for a CC Number. It successfully checks whether the number entered is valid or not. However I don't understand how to add user-defined functions for the program to determine whether that CC number is American Express, MasterCard or Visa card number, since all those cards have a different format.

**Current output :**

```
Hello! This is a Credit Card validation program.
                                                
Please enter your credit card number : (user input : 378282246310005 - valid cc number)

Your credit card number is true
```

**Expected output :**

```
Hello! This is a Credit Card validation program.
                                                
Please enter your credit card number : (user input : 378282246310005 - valid cc number)

Your credit card number is true and is an American Express CC Number(or Visa/Mastercard, depending on user's input)
```

Code : https://pastebin.com/bHSsSCPV

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    //concatenating the isValid variable into output (string concatonation)
        System.out.println("Hello! This is a Credit Card validation program.");
        System.out.println("                                                ");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter your credit card number : ");
        String creditCardNumber = sc.nextLine();
        boolean isValid = validateCreditCardNumber(creditCardNumber);
        System.out.println("                                                ");
        System.out.println("Your credit card number is " +isValid);
    }

private static boolean validateCreditCardNumber(String input) 
   {    

    //Input conversion to int
    int[] creditCardInt = new int [input.length()];
    
    
    //doubling each other digit starting from the right, if > than 9, mod 10 and + 1 to the remainder
    for (int i = 0; i <input.length(); i++ )
    {
        creditCardInt[i] = Integer.parseInt(input.substring (i, i + 1));
    }
    
    for (int i = creditCardInt.length - 2; i >= 0; i = i - 2)
    {
        int tempValue = creditCardInt[i];
        tempValue = tempValue * 2;
        if (tempValue > 9)
        {
            tempValue = tempValue % 10 + 1;
        }
        creditCardInt[i] = tempValue; 
    }

    //+ all the digits
    int total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < creditCardInt.length; i++)
    {
        total += creditCardInt [i];
    }
    
    //If number is a multiple of 10, it is valid..else it is invalid
    if (total % 10 == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }   
}   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple web search on `credit card number format` provided this.

> Visa cards – Begin with a 4 and have 13 or 16 digits. Mastercard cards – Begin with a 5 and has 16 digits. American Express cards – Begin with a 3, followed by a 4 or a 7 has 15 digits. ... Diners Club and Carte Blanche cards – Begin with a 3, followed by a 0, 6, or 8 and have 14 digits.

I suggest you continue searching the web for the appropriate format breakdown as well as the validation process (all cards may not validate the same way) including applying the CCV or equivalent value.  Then you just call the appropriate method to validate the card.  Note that some cards may have some common processes which means they could share another method.